# How can terminal colours on Cloud9 be changed?

Tags: configuration, cloud9

I'm trying to use vim via the terminal on Cloud9, and whilst functionally it works perfectly, I can't get themes to work properly.

I've tried [Molokai](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai) and [Badwolf](https://github.com/sjl/badwolf) (putting `colorscheme molokai` or `colorscheme badwolf` in `~/.vimrc`), but neither look like the screenshots provided. I've also tried changing the theme in Preferences → Themes, but the terminal background appears to be being set to either white (flat theme) or dark blue (classic theme) instead of actual black.

I'm aware of the way terminal colours work (the application says 'red' and the terminal interprets that however it's been configured, whether that's #FF0000 or #CC2323), but I can't find an obvious way to change this palette of colours in Cloud9.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and use of the built-in editor (Ace) in vim mode, I've found that you can change the terminal text, background and selection colours in the preferences under **Preferences → Settings → Editors → Terminal**.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because Cloud9 leverages `screen` as a terminal. Screen sets the `$TERM` environment variable to `screen`, which Vim does not recognize.

This is solved by adding `set t_Co=256` to your `.vimrc` file, which tells Vim that the terminal is capable of displaying 256 colors. This is the case, since the current release of Cloud9 is based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, where `screen` is capable of displaying 256 colors.

This addition produces the following:

[image: 256 Color Support]

Running `export TERM=xterm-256color` or `export TERM=xterm` before invoking Vim will have similar results:

[image: TERM set to xterm]

Alternatively, you can add the following to your .vimrc to set `TERM` appropriately when Vim is invoked:

```
if match($TERM, "screen")!=-1
  set term=xterm
endif
```